# Cast to ObjectId failed for value "ULID_ID" at path "docA"

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to get ULID working with mongoose.

My DocTypeA schema looks like this:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
const ULID = require('ulid')

const schema = new Schema({
  _id: { type: Schema.Types.String, default: () => ULID.ulid(Date.now()) },
  name: { type: Schema.Types.String },
})

schema.set('toJSON', {
  virtuals: true,
  versionKey: false,
  transform: function (doc, ret) {
    // remove these props when object is serialized
    delete ret._id
  },
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('DocTypeA', schema)
```

My DocTypeB schema looks like this:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
const ULID = require('ulid')

const schema = new Schema({
  _id: { type: Schema.Types.String, default: () => ULID.ulid(Date.now()) },
  name: { type: Schema.Types.String },
  docA: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'DocTypeA' },
})

schema.set('toJSON', {
  virtuals: true,
  versionKey: false,
  transform: function (doc, ret) {
    // remove these props when object is serialized
    delete ret._id
  },
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('DocTypeB', schema)
```

I am able to create documents for `DocTypeA` and ULID generated stuff is saved as _id in `DocTypeA` documents.
But when I try to reference a `DocTypeA` document id while creating an `DocTypeB` document, I get the cast error (mentioned in the title).

Here is the code for creating a `DocTypeA`:

```js
const create = async (payload) => {
  const docA = new DocTypeA(payload)
  await docA.save()
  return docA
}
```

For creating an `DocTypeB`, I am using:

```js
const create = async (payload) => {
  const docB = new DocTypeB(payload)
  await docB.save()
  return docB
}
```

Comment: Why did you used `docA: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'DocTypeA' }` in `doctypeb` schema? I think you have to use `docA: { type: Schema.Types.String, ref: 'DocTypeA' }`

Comment: Do string refs work? So mongoose just uses ref to figure out which collection to look in, and checks whether the type of _id is same as mentioned in the reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ULID are not qualified [`ObjectId`](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/v4.2.2/src/objectid.ts).
They are not hexadecimal strings and are 26-char length identifiers.

Given the way schema for `DocTypeB` is declared, `docA` field should be of `String` type and not `ObjectId`.

Your schema definition for `DocTypeB` should be as follows.

```js
const schema = new Schema({
  _id: { type: Schema.Types.String, default: () => ULID.ulid(Date.now()) },
  name: { type: Schema.Types.String },
  docA: { type: Schema.Types.String, ref: 'DocTypeA' },
});
```

Otherwise, Mongoose will try casting the identifier as `ObjectId` and that will throw.

```js
async function create() {
  const docA = new DocTypeA({name: 'Jack'})
  await docA.save()
 
  const docB = new DocTypeB(
    {name: 'Jill', docA} // Or {name: 'Jill', docA: docA._id})
  ) 
  await docB.save();
}

create().then(console.log('done')).catch(console.error)
```

**Note that**, a unique index is automatically added for [`_id` field](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/core/indexes-introduction/#default-id) in the collection so you must be careful not set the same value for it in different documents.

Comment: I got the problem. Could you add the necessary changes that I should make so that I can use ULID and mongoose populate? 
Does mongoose work with type: string and a ref attribute?
Or should I setup populate using virtuals as in https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals?

Comment: @Akshay You should be able to use any supported type for the _id field. You only need to pay attention that the value set for it in documents within a collection is unique.